# Logic about dates in PHP

Tags: php, html, date, logic

I'm creating a report in php in which 6 html drop downs appear and prompt the user to enter the two dates in which they would like to see the data of the report. So for example the report goes as follows:

See data between: [month][day][year] and [month][day][year] (where the brackets signify a select tag)

Also in this report is a function which calculates the percentage increase or decrease from the previous day. So for example if the user does not select any date range, it's simply data of the current day and the percentage is calculated as:

```
round(((($newDataPointCount - $yesterdayDataPointCount) / $yesterdayDataPointCount) * 100),2)
```

This is obviously very easy to calculate for only one day because I can tell it to query the SQL database with INTERVAL 1 DAY. But here is my question, how would I calculate the number of day intervals if the months change?

Everything would work great if the user stays within one month so it would be something like [March][20][2012] - [March][29][2012], and I can easily calculate the value is 9, but when it's something like [February][27][2012] - [March][20][2012], how can I calculate the number of days in between?

Just to clarify any questions that may arise, I'm using PHP and MySQL and would prefer to stay within those bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL DATEDIFF function should accomplish the task

[DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: I just checked out the php date->diff function. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Dates are not scalars and should not be treated as such.  My advice is to user the proper tools for date arithmetic.

A lot of people suggest unix timestamp oriented date math:

```
$a = '2012-02-12 14:03:50';
$b = '2012-05-30 00:55:03';
$days = (strtotime($b) - strtotime($a))/86400;
```

However, daylight saving time and all of kinds of factors can make that type of math wrong.

My approach is to typically use DateTime:

```
$a = new DateTime('2012-02-12 14:03:50');
$b = new DateTime('2012-05-30 00:55:03');
$diff = $b->diff($a);
//$diff is now a DateInterval
```

However, to answer your real question, I would not pull the data from MySQL based on MySQL date math, but rather I would just give it dates.

```
WHERE d >= '2012-02-27' AND d <= '2012-03-29';
```

Though based on your requirements, you may need to alter the 27 to 26 as to grab the previous day and do the calculations with it.

As for doing the changes in point values, I would either precalculate and store them, or I would just calculate them in PHP.  There's no simple way to tell SQL "hey grab every record between these dates and while you're at it, do some math with each record's previous record."

I hope this has been clear, but I have a feeling it borders on rambling other than clarity, so if so, please let me know and I'll edit my answer.